# Storing huge amount of data

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, performance

Apologies for the broadness of this question, but looking for a bit of advice.

I have built a system in Laravel.  A user is able to upload a file.  This file is then sent to a system that does some data science stuff on it.  It sends a response back to my system as a JSON string which I then save back to a JSON file.  This file is then loaded in the frontend so some charts can be displayed.

For this most part this approach has been fine. However, when I upload really large files (which is fine because I am chunk uploading), the saved JSON file is then huge.  This then becomes a problem because it is too big for the frontend to load.  A single file can contain hundreds of thousands rows of data.

So my question is really about what other options I have.  Instead of saving the response as a JSON file, is it okay to save these 300k+ rows to a mySQL database or is this too much for it to handle?  Should I use something like MongoDB instead?

I am thinking that a database is probably the best route as I can then query the specific data I need for each chart, without having to load a huge file just to extract it.  I do use the other data within the file, but this can be queried on an event so not as worried about this.

My concern is that if just 3 people upload a file, I could then have a database with over a million rows.  How can I then scale this, how can I ensure I wont have issues the more users that use the system?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.  I am starting to think that I may need to deploy a database server per user and auto prune their data every X days.

Thanks

Comment: What about JSON columns in MySQL? Have you looked at using Postgres as an alternative since it has really deep JSON support? There's generally no such thing as "too much for MySQL to handle", same as with any modern database. There is such a thing as "too much for your hardware configuration and/or server tuning".

Comment: Need more specifics about the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300k rows is not a problem. I support MySQL databases with several *billion* rows in a single table. You may need to upgrade to a larger, more powerful server, but MySQL can store it.

That said, you're on the right track thinking about how much data you want to retain and how much you need to prune.

Scalability depends more on optimizing the queries you need to run, not just on the number of rows you store.

So you should test the queries your app runs, and see how many rows it takes before you see performance decline. Try to optimize the queries by the usual techniques like adding indexes, or rewriting the SQL logic, or partitioning the data, etc. (many techniques, too much to get into in a Stack Overflow answer).

If you have optimized the queries as much as you can, then you need to start pruning data, or splitting data over multiple MySQL instances.